# Namespace dependencies not required

Tags: r

I am trying to build an R package so reading the manual on CRAN.
I could figure out that using imports to load functions in your namespace would be the best bet to use in the Description file.
After adding to the description file, I also added it to the namespace file.
I added importFrom to the namespace file with the functions required.

Now when I run R CMD check on my package,
I get an ERROR as

> Namespace dependencies not required :
> 'ggplot2'

Further information : Even if I add the package to the Depends in the description file, they are not getting loaded.

Please help with this.

Please find my description file below

```
Package: bigpackage
Type: Package
Title: Some title
Version: 1.0
Date: 2012-10-25
Author: Mayank Bansal
Maintainer: somename
Imports : R(>= 2.15.1), SweaveListingUtils( >=0.5.5),xtable(>=1.7-0),
        brew(>=1.0-6), knitr(>=0.8), RHive(>= 0.0-6), ggplot2(>=0.9.2)
        , brew, knitr
SystemRequirements : LaTeX(texi2dvi) must be present in the system to
        create PDF reports
Description: Some Description
License: file LICENSE
LazyLoad: yes
ByteCompile: true
OS_type : unix
```

Comment: Are you importing anything from `ggplot2` directly in your NAMESPACE file?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

If you use `import` or `importFrom` in your NAMESPACE file, you should have an entry for that package in the Imports section of your DESCRIPTION file (unless there is a reason that you need to use Depends in which case the package should have an entry in Depends, and not Imports)

Here is a relevant section of [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Specifying-imports-and-exports)

> The ‘Imports’ field lists packages whose namespaces are imported from (as specified in the NAMESPACE file) but which do not need to be attached. Namespaces accessed by the ‘::’ and ‘:::’ operators must be listed here, or in ‘Suggests’ or ‘Enhances’ (see below). Ideally this field will include all the standard packages that are used, and it is important to include S4-using packages (as their class definitions can change and the DESCRIPTION file is used to decide which packages to re-install when this happens). Packages declared in the ‘Depends’ field should not also be in the ‘Imports’ field.

---

I made a package with a single function `f`.  I made a NAMESPACE file with the same `importFrom` line that you say you have in yours.

**NAMESPACE file**

```
export("f")
importFrom("ggplot2","ggplot","geom_histogram")
```

At this point, if I run `R CMD check`, as expected, I get an error:

> Namespace dependency not required: ‘ggplot2’

But, if I add `Imports: ggplot2` to the DESCRIPTION such that my DESCRIPTION file is as follows, it passes `R CMD check` with no problems.

**DESCRIPTION file**

```
Package: anRpackage
Type: Package
Title: What the package does (short line)
Version: 1.0
Date: 2012-11-07
Author: Me
Maintainer: Who to complain to <yourfault@somewhere.net>
Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
License: GPL
Imports: ggplot2
```

Comment: Won't it fail R CMD check if you don't include the Imports section in the DESCRIPTION though?

Comment: @Dason, No. See the [DESCRIPTION](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/xts/DESCRIPTION?view=markup&root=xts) and [NAMESPACE](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/xts/NAMESPACE?view=markup&root=xts) of the xts package for example... `Depends: ggplot2` may need to be in the DESCRIPTION file for the OP though

Comment: You should have it in the imports field, and not in the depends field.

Comment: @GSee - yeah but that has zoo under depends and doesn't have any imports of zoo in the namespace.  I was saying that if you have an imports in your namespace but don't list the import in your DESCRIPTION then it will fail R CMD check - correct?  I think the OP is just confused about what an import does exactly and they're expected that it behaves similar to Depends.  If they want to use Depends then they don't need to add the package to their namespace and if they want to use imports they need something in an Imports field and in the namespace.

Comment: It will not fail R CMD check, but it may make @hadley angry ;-).  If they use Depends, they still may want to `importFrom` or `import` if they are using more than one package that both have a function with the same name and want to be certain of which is used in their package.

Comment: I just created a test package and didn't put ggplot2 in either Depends or Imports but included import(ggplot2) in the namespace.  It failed R CMD check with "Namespace dependency not required: ‘ggplot2’" <- sounds familiar.

Comment: @Dason, Yes. it has to be in one or the other.  When I first read the OP, I thought they were using Depends.  After re-reading it, it's not clear what the DESCRIPTION file looks like (but it sounds like it had a problem if the package in Depends wasn't loaded).  Anyway, if they don't have a reason to attach **ggplot2**, hadley is correct that Imports is generally preferable.

Comment: I don't have a reason to use ggplot2 as depends, I added ggplot2 as an imports package in the description file with the correct package version, added importFrom("ggplot2","ggplot","geom_histogram") in the namespace file.
Now when I perform a R CMD check on the package, it gives me the error mentioned above,

Comment: @MayankBansal, I will experiment when I have minute. Try not quoting, and using more than one `importFrom`. for example: `importFrom(ggplot2, ggplot)`, then on a separate line, `importFrom(ggplot2, geom_histogram)`.  Also, in your DESCRIPTION file, you have a line that reads `Imports: ggplot2`, right?

Comment: Ok i will also try your suggestion and yes I am mentioning ggplot2 as Imports in the DESCRIPTION file.

Comment: The only thing that my description file has extra is version numbers.
Is there a limit on the number of packages you can specify in Imports.

Comment: Finally! you've shown your DESCRIPTION file.  Now the problem is clear.  You have a space between "Imports" and ":", it should be `Imports: `, not `Imports : `

Comment: Also,  `R(>= 2.15.1)` should go in Depends, not Imports.  And, you should be aware that "Version requirements can be specified [in Imports], but will not be checked when the namespace is loaded (whereas they are checked by R CMD check)"

Comment: ok , I will check it out and get back to you.
Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: Thank you so much !!! it worked finally :) 
There was a problem with mentioning version numbers also , I removed the version numbers, its not that essential for me

Comment: @MayankBansal, maybe the problem is not with the version requirements, but that brew and knitr are listed twice?

Comment: When i tried, the packages weren't listed twice, it had issues with the special characters in the version ('-',and more than one '.').
It did not give me an error with the version number for knitr because it was just >=0.8

Answer (score 9):

A simple reason this can happen is if you accidentally used commas when declaring `@import` in any/all of your functions

E.g. this

```
#'
#' @import rvest, dplyr, stringr, jsonlite
#'
#' @export
#'
```

should be changed to this

```
#'
#' @import rvest dplyr stringr jsonlite
#'
#' @export
#'
```

This is a common error since packages *are* comma-separated in the `DESCRIPTION` file