# character(0) warnings when running devtools::load_all(".") in RStudio

Tags: r, devtools, package-development

I have an R package that I've been building in RStudio, let's called it `my_pkg`. When I run `devtools::load_all(".")` within RStudio (specifically using the `Ctrl + Shift + L` shortcut), I get the following message:

```
Loading my_pkg
Warning messages:
1: character(0) 
2: character(0) 
3: character(0) 
4: character(0) 
5: character(0)
```

All of the functions in the package work fine. My `NAMESPACE` and `DESCRIPTION` files are complete with no syntax errors. When I run `?my_pkg`, however, the help file does not match the specifications provided in the `DESCRIPTION` file. When I remove the `Imports` from `DESCRIPTION`, there is no more `character(0)` warning message. Of course, I need those imports. When I change `Imports` to `Suggests`, there is `character(0)` warning message.

Here is the description file content, with some stuff changed to protect IP.

```
Package: scoutdroid
Title: This is where the title is.
Version: 0.1
Authors@R: "Ben Hanowell <benjamin.hanowell@redfin.com> [aut, cre]"
Description: This is where the description is.
Depends:
    R (>= 3.1.0)
Imports:
    dplyr,
    lubridate,
    mboost,
    randomForestSRC,
    RODBC,
    stringr
License: file LICENSE
LazyData: true
```

And here is `NAMESPACE`.

```
# Generated by roxygen2 (4.0.1): do not edit by hand

import(RODBC)
import(dplyr)
import(lubridate)
import(mboost)
import(parallel)
import(randomForestSRC)
import(stringr)
```

When I use the RStudio Build & Reload button in the Build tab, I get the following warnings:

** preparing package for lazy loading

```
Warning: replacing previous import by 'lubridate::intersect' when loading 'scoutdroid'
Warning: replacing previous import by 'lubridate::setdiff' when loading 'scoutdroid'
Warning: replacing previous import by 'lubridate::union' when loading 'scoutdroid'
```

**edit** Added some more details to help folks understand what might be going on.

**edit 2** I also added the `DESCRIPTION` file, although I don't provide the full package, which is proprietary.

**edit 3** Added `NAMESPACE`.

**edit 4** Added warnings that occur when using RStudio Build & Reload button in the Build tab.

Comment: Is your package on github

Comment: No. It is proprietary. *edit* It is on Bitbucket, but access is private.

Comment: Well good luck. Maybe you could try making a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: The last time [something similar happened](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085481/namespace-dependencies-not-required/13261139#comment18121469_13261139) it turned out there was a problem with the DESCRIPTION file afterall

Comment: If it is something wrong with the DESCRIPTION file, then why does the problem go away when I replace Imports with Suggests?

Comment: You're using the fact that changing the DESCRIPTION file "fixes" the problem as evidence that there isn't a problem with the DESCRIPTION file?  Are you able to build, check, and install the package without using `load_all`?  I think seeing the NAMESPACE file would help, but that might be getting too much into your proprietary code.  I suggest trying to make a simple package with only one function and see if you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: # Generated by roxygen2 (4.0.1): do not edit by hand

import(RODBC)
import(dplyr)
import(lubridate)
import(mboost)
import(parallel)
import(randomForestSRC)
import(stringr)

Comment: I could be totally wrong, but my hunch is that those "warnings" are "replacing previous import" warnings that devtools is trying to suppress. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18403565/967840

Comment: You are totally right. I built and reloaded. package::lubridate is the problem. You know how to fix that?

Comment: Don't import those functions from lubridate.  Use `importFrom` to only import the functions that you actually use.  I think @hadley was working on an `@autoimport` tag in roxygen3 that might do this for you, but I don't know the status of roxygen3 or if it's been integrated into RStudio.

Comment: Tried it. IT WORKED! Thanks @GSee. I believe this is the second time you've saved my tookus this week.

Comment: @GSee, I would upvote the ever-living crud out of your answer and then check it if you wrote it up.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

After some dialoge in the comments, we figured out that the empty warnings that `load_all` is giving you are actually initiated when loading the package because of function name conflicts.

The issue is that you are importing a function from a package, then overwriting that function.  When that happens R throws warnings as you saw when you clicked "Build & Reload" in RStudio:

```
Warning: replacing previous import by 'lubridate::intersect' when loading 'scoutdroid'
Warning: replacing previous import by 'lubridate::setdiff' when loading 'scoutdroid'
Warning: replacing previous import by 'lubridate::union' when loading 'scoutdroid'
```

It looks like `load_all` may be attempting to muffle those warnings (just a guess) which is why you see `character(0)` instead of the actual warnings. (These particular warnings are difficult to silence.)

It is generally not a good idea to import an entire package's namespace.  You should instead import only the symbols you need.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18403565/967840) of mine for more.

The solution is to use `importFrom` instead of `import` in your NAMESPACE file.

Comment: For others comming here, looking for solutions. When you run `devtools::check`, the warnings above will show

Answer (score 2):

It can also be due to a broken link in the `roxygen2` documentation. For example when you link to a function external to your package with the wrong name, say `\link[stringi]{STRI_C}` instead of `\link[stringi]{stri_c}`

Comment: Thanks, Duccio. The checked answer ending up explaining the issue, but this could in other cases, so I upvoted it.