# Namespace dependencies not required error although I've used Imports in DESCRIPTION

Tags: r, r-package

I received the following error when running `R CMD check`:

`Namespace dependencies not required: 'foreach' 'ggplot2' 'magrittr'`

I've found [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085481/namespace-dependencies-not-required#13261139) and follow the answer there by making sure that the packages are included in the `Imports` field of my DESCRIPTION file, but I still received the error.

Here is my DESCRIPTION file

```
Type: Package
Title: mytitle
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: c(
    person("John", "Doe", email = "johndoe@example.com", role = c("aut", "cre")),
    )
Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
    Use four spaces when indenting paragraphs within the Description.
License: What license is it under?
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
Depends:
    R (>= 3.1)
Imports:
    cowplot (>= 0.9.2),
    data.table (>= 1.11.4),
    doParallel (>= 1.0.11),
    foreach (>= 1.2.0),
    GA (>= 3.1.1),
    ggplot2 (>= 2.1.0),
    hydroGOF (>= 0.3.10),
    magrittr (>= 1.4),
    parallel (>= 3.5.0),
    Rcpp (>= 0.12.16)
RoxygenNote: 6.1.0
Roxygen:
    list(markdown = TRUE)
LinkingTo: 
    Rcpp,
    RcppArmadillo    
Suggests: 
    testthat
```

And here is my NAMESPACE file created by Roxygen:

```
export(myfunction)
import(data.table)
import(ggplot2)
importFrom(Rcpp,evalCpp)
importFrom(cowplot,plot_grid)
importFrom(doParallel,registerDoParallel)
importFrom(foreach,"%dopar%")
importFrom(foreach,foreach)
importFrom(hydroGOF,KGE)
importFrom(hydroGOF,NSE)
importFrom(hydroGOF,rmse)
importFrom(hydroGOF,ssq)
importFrom(magrittr,"%>%")
importFrom(parallel,detectCores)
importFrom(parallel,makeCluster)
importFrom(parallel,stopCluster)
useDynLib(mytitle, .registration = TRUE)
```

Can you please tell me what I missed?

Comment: What are you trying to do with them? It sounds a bit like you are really wanting to use `Suggests`: [link](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html)

Comment: I need to use `Imports` rather than `Suggests` because I'm using `ggplot()`, `%>%` and `foreach()` in my package code.

Comment: For some reason, when I removed `Depends: R (>= 3.1)` then it works. Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When R CMD check runs, it built a binary package .zip file on the parent folder of the package's folder, and also a folder call pkgname.check. I think the next time R CMD check runs, it may not rebuild that folder or that file, depending on whether changes have been made in the package. I deleted those file and folder and rebuild, everything works.